# Eigenvalues - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $c$ is eigenvalue for matrix B.
How can I prove than $c^k$ is eigenvalue for matrix $B^k$?
am not sure what I should try here...will appreciate your help

Comment: Start by taking an eigenvector for $B$,$c$.

Comment: @julien ok if I know Bv=cV than...?

Comment: Then $B^2v=BBv=Bcv=cBv=c^2v$...

Comment: @julien oh thanks that is so easy... :)

Answer (score 1):

Induction...?

$$B(v)=cv\Longrightarrow B^k(v)=B(B^{k-1}v)\stackrel{\text{Ind. hypothesis}}=B(c^{k-1}v)=c^{k-1}Bv=c^{k-1}cv=c^kv$$